# Slim Site, Not many requests, High load time

Tags: wordpress, performance, server, shared-hosting

I have been optimising my site for load time and have managed to get my site down to <700kb with only 34 requests.

However, it's still not exactly snappy. On http://tools.pingdom.com/ it is apparently "slower than 75% of tested sites". Which is strange for a sub-1mb site with not many requests. The site is www.succeedenglish.com. It has just launched and is seeing about 30 visitors per day so it can't be traffic volume.

The problem I guess is the server. When I run a test on Pingdom, the URL makes up 5.5 seconds of a 6.25 second load time. A similar result is seen on http://www.webpagetest.org/

What does that URL mean? and how can I solve it?

The site is on WordPress with a Bluehost shared plan. I know shared isn't the best but it should be able to handle such a small site with so few visitors.

I'd really really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Shared" and cheap hosting would mean that you share resourses with maybe 100k other hosted applications. This has significant implications if there are a small amount of, say, RAM or CPU power or if another of the applications are hogging them. Think of the "domain" here as the account on which you are serving your application (website). I would recommend a VPS, Linode is a good provider. You have a guaranteed set of resources solely for you and not at the whim of any other user.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is hardly a programming question. It is more suited for [webmaster.se] or [wordpress.se]

Comment: id say try wp super cache (to serve pre-saved html files ) if not upgrade...but general things to watch out for when working with wp are expensive loops run twice or 3 times, loads of wp_options that autoload etc.

Answer (score 1):

After having a look at the speed test on pingdom, I noticed something that is unnecessarily adding 2.2 seconds to the load time. The URL request is being doubled.

Heres why, when you try to access **www.succeedenglish.com** you will notice that your wordpress website is redirecting to **succeedenglish.com** (without the **www**).

I did a test without the www and its faster:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dM0eyP/succeedenglish.com

This is because the website URL in the settings found in the WP backend is set without the "**www**".

Heres my suggestion, login to the backend of wordpress and update the URL to include the "www".

You will find the fields to update under "General Settings". You will have to update 2 fields: **"WordPress Address (URL)"** and **"Site Address (URL)"**

That will sort out the unnecessary redirect onload.

However, if you also have images (image URLs) within posts and custom fields (used by some plugins), you would need to update all the URLs throughout the database.

To do this you can use a simple plugin called **Velvet Blues Update URLs**.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

You can install it via the WordPress backend and then access the plugin here: Tools -> Update URLs.

What you want to do is replace all "http://succeedenglish.com/" urls with "http://www.succeedenglish.com/". **Please remember to include the "http://", otherwise you will end up with incorrect URLs, just be cautious**

Just be sure to check out the plugins instructions.

This will improve the load time.

Let me know if you come right.

Comment: If this is helpful, please upvote or mark as the correct answer. It would contribute to my stackoverflow reputation. Good luck!